# Question About Eigenvectors and Matrix Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I am self-studying some basic linear algebra. I encountered the following theorem:

> **Theorem**$\quad$ Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.
>
> 1. $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if it has eigenvectors $\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2},\dots,\mathbf{x_n}$ such that the matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x_1} & \mathbf{x_2} & \dots & \mathbf{x_n}\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible.
> 2. When this is the case, $P^{-1}AP=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)$, where, for each $i$, $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to $\mathbf{x_i}$.

I was wondering if this theorem is the same as the following statement:

> **Statement**$\quad$ An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, that is, $P^{-1}AP=D$ is diagonal for some invertible $n \times n$ matrix P, if and only if the diagonal entries of $D$ are eigenvalues of $A$ and the columns of $P$ are corresponding eigenvectors.

Here is some of my thought: ***I do not think these two statements are the same***, and ***I do not think the second statement is correct***. Because, since there could be multiple eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue, and not every such corresponding eigenvectors might make the matrix consisting of them as columns invertible (and thus a diagonalizing matrix).

More specifically, denote the diagonalized matrix $D=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0         & \dots  & 0        \\
            0         & \lambda_2 & \dots  & 0        \\
            \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots   \\
            0         & 0         & \dots  & \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$. Suppose, for simplicity, that, for $i = 2, \dots, n$, there are only one eigenvector $\mathbf{x_i}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. But there are more than one (say two) eigenvectors $\mathbf{x_1}$ and $\mathbf{x_1}'$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, and that only one of them (say $\mathbf{x_1}$) can make the matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x_1} & \mathbf{x_2} & \dots & \mathbf{x_n}\end{pmatrix}$ invertible. In such case, the second statement would not hold.

Is my thought correct? If so, could someone please give a concrete numerical example showing that the reasoning I provided above is indeed possible. If my thought is wrong, could someone please correct me with a proof? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: the usual phrasing:  a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if there is a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for your comment. I haven't got to the chapter on basis. But I just looked it up. I found that $P=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x_1}&\dots&\mathbf{x_n}\end{pmatrix}$, where the $\mathbf{x_i}$'s are eigenvectors of $A$, is invertible $\iff$ the columns of $P$ are linearly independent and spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a basis $\{\mathbf{x_1},\dots,\mathbf{x_n}\}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. But this doesn't answer my question. My problem is mainly on the second statement in my post: Whether the statement is the same as the theorem and whether it's correct?

Comment: Write $P^{-1}AP=D$ as $AP=PD$ to see that the columns of $P$ must be eigenvectors and the diagonal elements of $D$ their corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for your comment. What you said is correct. But this is not what I am asking. Here is my question: If the theorem were to be stated as the second statement, what would happen if there are more than one eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue in the diagonal of $D$ such that not all of the eigenvectors can make $P$ an invertible matrix? If this is possible, then the second statement in my post would be wrong.

Comment: Yes. The direction that $P^{-1}AP=D$ follows from some properties of $P$ is not well-formulated in the second statement. Will Jagy has already criticised that. Let's throw that  bad statement into the bin and press on with the correct first statement.